# Determine if a Windows Shutdown has been canceled

Tags: windows, windows-services, shutdown

I have a service that runs within a VM.  When the user requests that the VM be shut down, I use the service to start a Windows shutdown by calling ExitWindowsEx() from a user-space program that runs in the context of the user that is currently logged in.

The shutdown that is initiated by ExitWindowsEx() can be canceled by other programs running, if for example they have documents open that have unsaved changes.

I need to determine from my service if the shutdown has been canceled.  I have found many ways to cancel or delay the shutdown from both the service and from a user-space executable, but I need a way to be notified (or even query) if the shutdown that I just initiated has been canceled by someone else.

Comment: But isn't there a chance that your program will no longer be running, even if the shutdown was cancelled?

Comment: @Hassan The service continues to run in the case where the shutdown is canceled since it is not stopped until after the user is logged out.

Comment: Why not call `BroadcastSystemMessage` before calling `ExitWindowsEx`? Using `BSF_QUERY` and `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` as the parameters.